# Playing random audio files in sequence with AKPlayer

Tags: audiokit

I am working on a sort of multiple audio playback project. First, I have 10 mp3 files in a folder. I wanted AKPlayer to play one of these audio files randomly, but in sequence - one after the other. But playing a random file after another random file seems to be tricky. Here's what I've written:

```
let file = try? AKAudioFile(readFileName: String(arc4random_uniform(9)+1) + ".mp3")

let player = AKPlayer(audioFile: file!)

player1.isLoopiong = true
player.buffering = .always

AudioKit.output = AKPlayer

try? AudioKit.start()
player.start(at: startTime)
```

This code loops the first chosen random file forever - but I simply wanted to play each random files once. Is there any way I can reload the 'file' so the player starts again when it's done playing? I've tried calling multiple AKPlayers (but calling 10 players must be wrong), if player.isPlaying = false, sequencer, etc, but couldn't exactly figure out how. Apologize for such a newbie question. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AKPlayer` has a completion handler

> to be called when Audio is done playing. The handler won’t be called
>   if stop() is called while playing or when looping from a buffer.

The completion handler type is `AKCallback`, which is a typealias for `() -> Void`. If you have some good reason not to use 10 `AKPlayer`s, you could probably use the completion handler to change the file and restart the player.  But you could also create an array with 10 `AKPlayer`s, each loaded with a different file, and have a function that selects a player at random for playback (or that cycles through a a pre-shuffled array).  The completion handler for each player in the array could call this function, when appropriate.  As per the doc quoted above, make sure that the `AKPlayer` is not looping or else the completion handler won't be called.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use the completionHandler of the player to load a new file into the same player when playback finishes. In your completion block:

```
player.load(url: nextFile)
player.play()
```

Another approach is to use the AKClipPlayer with 10 clips of a predetermined random order and schedule them in sequence. This method will be the most seamless (if that matters).